# How to proceed Angular's output twice in a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/pbyhz24k/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['rzModule']);

myApp.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.priceSlider = {
        value: 200,
        options: {
            floor: 0,
            ceil: 500
        }
    }
}
```

There is exactly a script I need, but I need 2 of those sliders. How can I make so?

Comment: have the second: `<rzslider rz-slider-model="vm.priceSlider2.value" rz-slider-options="vm.priceSlider2.options"></rzslider>` with `vm.priceSlider2 = {...}` in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['rzModule']);

myApp.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.priceSlider = {
        value: 200,
        options: {
            floor: 0,
            ceil: 500
        }
    }
    vm.priceSliderAnother = {
        value: 200,
        options: {
            floor: 0,
            ceil: 500
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
        <p>Price: {{vm.priceSlider.value}}</p>
        <rzslider rz-slider-model="vm.priceSlider.value" rz-slider-options="vm.priceSlider.options"></rzslider>
        <p>Price: {{vm.priceSliderAnother.value}}</p>
        <rzslider rz-slider-model="vm.priceSliderAnother.value" rz-slider-options="vm.priceSliderAnother.options"></rzslider>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great! Thanks! What di I do next to e.g. output sum of prices in a div?
<p>{{vm.priceSlider.value}} + {{vm.priceSlider.value}}</p>
This does not work.

Comment: You should try with onChange function if have, it should be.

Comment: You left nothing to do for me :) Will study hard how You did it.Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of data

```
vm.sliders = [
   {
      value: 200,
      options: {
         floor: 0,
         ceil: 500
      }
   },
   {
      value: 200,
      options: {
         floor: 0,
         ceil: 500
      }
   },
   {
      value: 200,
      options: {
         floor: 0,
         ceil: 500
      }
   }
]
```

and use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in the template

```
<rzslider ng-repeat="slide in vm.sliders" rz-slider-model="slide.value" rz-slider-options="slide.options"></rzslider>
```

I didn't test this, I'm not into Angular 1 anymore, but the approach is this.